# How do I build sqlite with static library also be compiled with -fPIC?

Tags: sqlite

I have compiled using below parameters

```
#./configure --prefix=/usr/local CFLAGS=-fPIC --enable-static --enable-shared   \
            CFLAGS="-g -O2 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3=1 \
            -DSQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA=1     \
            -DSQLITE_ENABLE_UNLOCK_NOTIFY=1       \
            -DSQLITE_SECURE_DELETE=1              \
            -DSQLITE_ENABLE_DBSTAT_VTAB=1"
# make -j 8
# make install
```

After using sqlite I get below error message:

```
/usr/bin/g++ -o utools/utools.so -Wl,-Bsymbolic -g -O2 -shared -Wl,-z,defs utools/utools.plugin.o utools/lib/libutools.a core/lib/libunv.a fv/lib/libfv.a sb/lib/libsb.a -lz -ldl
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/sqlite/lib/libsqlite3.a(sqlite3.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/sqlite/lib/libsqlite3.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
scons: *** [stdarm/stdarm.so] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Comment: Why are you compiling SQLite as a library? It is [recommended](http://www.sqlite.org/custombuild.html) to just add `sqlite3.c` to your project.

Comment: Hi, thanks for respoding. can you please help me how to get rid this error. 

/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/sqlite/lib/libsqlite3.a(sqlite3.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/sqlite/lib/libsqlite3.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
scons: *** [stdarm/stdarm.so] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.

Comment: How to re-compile sqlite 3.9.2 with -fPIC?

Answer (score 2):

inside `/usr/local/lib/` directory, deleting following files worked for me

- libsqlite3.a
- libsqlite3.la
- libsqlite3.o.0.bak
- libsqlite3.so

I think these files are from the older versions of libsqlite3,
because when you type and check `dpkg -L libsqlite3-dev`, none goes to `/usr/local/lib/`

I took the reference from [sqlite3 breakage](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-ports/2014-October/096006.html)